# How can I redirect a url that I am pointed to after clicking submit?

Tags: php, javascript, html, xml, forms

There is a html form I have which submits to a Servlet once Submit button is clicked. After the submission the Servlet redirects to a fixed url which is

http://siteforServlets.com/Servlet/Servlet

That site then displays an xml report shown below:

Sorry I cannot post Images not enough rep so I uploaded direct link here: 
http://img836.imageshack.us/img836/3343/sitea.png

I dont want my users getting confused seeing an xml I prefer it going blank page or redirecting to a different url...

How can I redirect the url to hide this xml report url?

Mark, I tried what you said but it redirects before the form even loads. Here is a quick jsfiddle I made to demonstrate your suggestion: jsfiddle.net/ujsEG/12/

Comment: is that xml page made by you or automatically generated by system?

Comment: its generated by the system automatically

Comment: cant you change in that xml? if you can just remove <?xml like tag above all and then it will be a blank page.

Comment: I wish I could but I have no access to any of that xml file or its components. I was hoping for some kind of redirect or such..

Comment: Is the servlet not on the same domain as the site? I'm guessing this is why you're not using AJAX to handle the response by the client?

Comment: you are correct, Servlet is on a different domain.

Comment: @Bool Tim: Look into jquery's $.ajax() method. They have cross-domain support via JSONP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try making the form target a hidden iframe and then set the `onload` attribute of the iframe with a javascript call to window.location.href.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var okToRedirect = false;
function redirect() {
    if (okToRedirect) {
        window.location.href = 'path/to/new/location';
    }
}
</script>

<form action="...some action..." target="MyIframe" onsubmit="okToRedirect = true;">
...
</form>

<iframe name="MyIframe" style="display: none;" onload="parent.redirect()"></iframe>
```

When the form posts, the results will display inside the hidden iframe. Once the iframe finishes loading, the `onload` attribute will fire the javascript to redirect the user.

**Update**

I updated my answer because of your comment. I added a javascript method which the iframe can call. There is now a global variable which is set to false initially. This will prevent the first load of the page from redirecting. When the form posts, the `onsubmit` event on the form will set the global variable `okToRedirect` to true, the iframe will reload and will call the `redirect()` method. This time around, the redirect will occur.

Comment: what you said I tried but as soon as the form even loads up it redirects...doesn't even wait for the form submission so I can't even fill the form..

Comment: @Bool Tim: You're right. Looks like onload will fire when the iframe first gets set up. I'll update my answer above. Basically you'll need to add some javascript that'll only do the redirect if the form is being submitted. Check back in a few....

Comment: @Bool Tim: I updated the answer. Alternatively you could use AJAX. JQuery makes that easy. Let me know if you need an example.

Comment: it works! your new solution works :D just out of curiosity, would it be possible to pull out the work order id from that xml thats displayed before it redirects? It would be very useful.

Comment: @Bool Tim: Good question but unfortunately I'm not sure because I've never tried it before. You could write your javascript function in such a way to try to get the element by tag name and get its value before doing the redirect. However, you might run into a security issue.